# How to hide JWT key from my Ocelot api gateway?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ocelot

I have a public ocelot api gateway with authentication through a jwt. The Key to check the JWT is within the start up within ocelot which is obviously very insecure. What are the best practises for hiding your JWT keys, particularly for an api gateway like Ocelot?

Comment: I'd suggest putting the key into environment variable and keep it outside your source codes. See [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables-1) for details

Answer (score -1):

Are you keep the key in appsettings ? If do, you can keep on secret section and get with same code. Check this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: anyway, that's not a production-ready solution, it can be used only in development